# How to remove " from a set in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a set created from a string called final that is returning:

```
myset = {final}
print(myset)
gives me the following:
{"{16: ['at', 'lane'], 25: ['Fell']}"}
```

I literally want to be able to extract the contents and create:

```
newset = {16: ['at', 'lane'], 25: ['Fell']}
```

I have tried to remove the the first {" and last "} however using .remove and .discard however they do not work. I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

I want to be able to create the following variable (without actually typing it) and not converting it to a string which will add comments i.e " :

```
newset = {13: ['at', 'lane'], 20: ['Fell']}
```

if i was to just print(newset) I want to literally return

```
 {13: ['at', 'lane'], 20: ['Fell']}
```

This is for an assignment and I am stuck - sorry for this stupid question.

Thanks in advance Jemma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `myset` using [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval). It's like JSON's parse, in which it parses a string and evaluates it in the namespace. Evaluating a string like this will result in a dictionary (`dict`).

Try

```
myset = eval(final) # evaluate string expression
print(myset)
```